# Dimple/D3 Pie chart with missing pieces

Tags: jquery, d3.js, charts, pie-chart, dimple.js

If I have a percentage of a pie chart say 90% is there a way in dimple to create a pie chart that only shows 90% and the other 10% is a missing slice? Thanks.

Comment: By 'missing' you mean like, the same colour as the background?

Comment: yes. A missing slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(Math.PI * 2);
```

Will set your start angle at 0, and then end at 2PI. you can multiply this however you wish to get your desired angle.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(70)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(2 * Math.PI * 0.9);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", arc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do I do it with dimple? I create the pie chart like this: var mySeries = myChart.addSeries('legend', dimple.plot.pie); I know d3 lies underneath so there must be a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: I still have an issue with using dimple. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383257/creating-an-imcomplete-pie-chart-in-dimple-js